# How to prepare the three-dimensional register S in HHL?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
In the original HHL paper, in step 4 of the $U_{\text{invert}}$ subroutine (Appendix A.1), it says to adjoin a three-dimensional register S in the state

$\ket{h(\lambda_k)} = \sqrt{1-f(\lambda_k)^2-g(\lambda_k)^2}\ket{\text{nothing}}+f(\lambda_k)\ket{\text{well}}+g(\lambda_k)\ket{\text{ill}}$.

I have played around with some possible controlled-rotation schemes to prepare this state, but with no luck. Does anyone know how to prepare this state?